# Make a wallpaper window clickable

Tags: c#, input, pinvoke, wallpaper

I created a library which lets you move any window behind the desktop icons using the `user32.dll`, but the problem is that the window doesn't react neither to clicks or key presses (even KeyboardDevice didn't seem to capture anything)'

One thing to note though is that after I make any window run on that wallpaper layer, it disappears from the task bar.

**This is the code:**

```
    public static void MoveBehindIcons(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
      IntPtr window = W32.FindWindow("Progman", (string) null);
      IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
      int num1 = 1324;
      IntPtr wParam = new IntPtr(0);
      IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
      int num2 = 0;
      int num3 = 1000;
      W32.SendMessageTimeout(window, (uint) num1, wParam, zero, (W32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags) num2, (uint) num3, out result);
      IntPtr workerw = IntPtr.Zero;
      W32.EnumWindows((W32.EnumWindowsProc) ((tophandle, topparamhandle) =>
      {
        if (W32.FindWindowEx(tophandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", IntPtr.Zero) != IntPtr.Zero)
          workerw = W32.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, tophandle, "WorkerW", IntPtr.Zero);
        return true;
      }), IntPtr.Zero);
      W32.SetParent(windowHandle, workerw);
    }
```

**the W32 class:** https://pastebin.com/Tw72Lbw6

WallpaperEngine can do it somehow..

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Could you at least explain why you downvoted whoever did please?

Comment: See msdn posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfc75b57-df16-48c6-92af-ea0a34f540ae/how-to-get-the-handle-of-a-window-that-i-click?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How can we give you advice on what we can't see. The code isn't here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you mean I provided a link to it

Comment: @TomLenc: Yeah, that's not **"here"**, and it's not the minimum code necessary to see the problem.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/103167)

Comment: A major problem with code links is that someone viewing the same question in the future won't see the same code, so the question and answers won't make sense.  Remember that Stack Overflow is an encyclopedia of Q&A, not a help service.  We want answers to help other programmers who have similar problems.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's true although the code is enormously long because of all the `user32.dll` bindings

Comment: @Tom You cut it down to a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I already did

Comment: Nope. You did not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know what else to provide. As I've said, whatever window is sent to that wallpaper layer doesn't receive click or keypress events.